# Pass parameter to the page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages, `p1.html` and `p2.html` with jQuery Mobile.

There is some links in `p1.html`, and all links are navigating to `p2.html` but with a little difference.

I want to pass an `int` parameter to `p2.html` javascript (for example, link number), So a javascript code in `p2.html`, make little changes to itself based on the `int` parameter (Before transition starts).

I want to use Ajax navigation feature and Transitions of jQuery Mobile, And I don't want use page anchors (`p2.html#6`).

How to send that parameter to `p2.html`?

Comment: check out this thread, it might help you out if you're thinking GET parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5448545/467164

Comment: @ZathrusWriter If I use that method, JQM will download that page many times (one time for each link) because URL is different, but the html content of all links are same. So it should be downloaded once... (`p2.html` is a big page and should **not** be downloaded many times...)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter That little difference in `p2.html` should made by client-side javascript code.

Comment: And how to detect if JQM is going to `p2.html` (and not other page) in `pagebeforechange` event?

Comment: Ok, Let me try it. Can you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use cookies to save the relevant information?

Get the [cookie jquery plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

p1.html

```
<a href="p2.html" data-p2data="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="p2.html" data-p2data="2">Link 2</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-p2data]').click(function(){
        $.cookie('p2data', $(this).data('p2data'));
    }
}
</script>
```

p2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p2data = $.cookie('p2data');
    // .. process the page based on the value in p2data.
</script>
```

Comment: I'd say using cookies to send parameters between pages is a bit of an overkill, taken into consideration they are used as a persistent storage

Comment: @ZathrusWriter But this method will work also on B-Grade browsers, which do not support Ajax navigation...

Comment: @AndrewR Can you provide a link for cookie jquery plugin? (I have found several plugins, I don't know which one do you mean)

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi true, that did not occur to me :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I agree, and normally I wouldn't suggest it. But given the parameters in the question it seems like the best solution.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi I found a write up of the cookie plugin and a link to the github page here http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) there is no built in way to pass parameters between pages.

However you can use one of the plugins mentioned there ([page-params](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) or [jquery-mobile-router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router)) or you can use localStorage or cookies.

Have a look at some of these SO questions

[Passing data between pages with jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671092/passing-data-between-pages-with-jquery-mobile)

[Passing parameters to a page-id in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238762/passing-parameters-to-a-page-id-in-jquery-mobile/8295488#8295488)

[How-to store variable beetween jQM pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739051/how-to-store-variable-beetween-jqm-pages/10739127#10739127)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable to store that numeric value when a link on page1.html is clicked:

```
$('a.special_link').click(function() {window.my_id = this.id});
```

... you will be then able to retrieve this in page2.html, since JQM uses AJAXed navigation by default, thus staying on a single page with this variable still accessible:

```
$('document').on('pagebeforechange', function(toPage, data) {
    if (toPage == 'page2.html') {
        alert('you have clicked on link number: ' + window.my_id);
    }
});
```